# Why output length is coming 6?

Tags: c

I have written a simple program to calculate length of string in this way. 
I know that there are other ways too. But I just want to know why this program is giving this output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     char str[1];
     printf( "%d", printf("%s", gets(str)));

     return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
(null)6
```

Comment: @timrau Any input would give a buffer overflow.

Comment: It looks like the input might be null, which if that's the case it means that it's reading uninitialized memory?

Comment: I'm not taking any input.

Comment: ( + n + u + l + l + ) = 6.:D

Comment: @vivekjain, `gets` waits for user input, so you have to be giving some input, somehow.

Comment: @vivekjain; When you are pressing only `Enter` key then you are passing `\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you always pass empty strings from the standard input, you are invoking undefined behavior, so the output could be pretty much anything, and it could crash as well. `str` cannot be a well-formed C string of more than zero characters.

`char str[1]` allocates storage room for one single character, but that character needs to be the `NUL` character to satisfy C string constraints. You need to create a character array large enough to hold the string that you're writing with `gets`.

"(null)6" as the output could mean that `gets` returned `NULL` because it failed for some reason or that the stack was corrupted in such a way that the return value was overwritten with zeroes (per the undefined behavior explanation). 6 following "(null)" is expected, as the return value of `printf` is the number of characters that were printed, and "(null)" is six characters long.

Answer (score 1):

It invokes undefined behavior. In this case you may get any thing. At least `str` should be of `2` bytes if you are not passing a empty string.

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues with your program.

First off, you're defining a char buffer way too short, a 1 char buffer for a string can only hold one string, the empty one.  This is because you need a null at the end of the string to terminate it.

Next, you're using the `gets` function which is very unsafe, (as your compiler almost certainly warned you about), as it just blindly takes input and copies it into a buffer.  As your buffer is 0+terminator characters long, you're going to be automatically overwriting the end of your string into other areas of memory which could and probably does contain important information, such as your `rsp` (your return pointer).  This is the classic method of smashing the stack.

Third, you're passing the output of a `printf` function to another `printf`.  `printf` isn't designed for formating strings and returning strings, there are other functions for that.  Generally the one you will want to use is `sprintf` and pass it in a string.

Please read the documentation on this sort of thing, and if you're unsure about any specific thing read up on it before just trying to program it in.  You seem confused on the basic usage of many important C functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable some space is reserved to store the value. 
The reserved space can be a space that was previously used by some other
code and has values. When the variable goes out of scope or is `free`d 
the value is not erased (or it may be, anything goes.) only the programs access 
to that variable is revoked.

When you read from an unitialised location you can get anything.

This is undefined behaviour and you are doing that,

Output on `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3` is `0`

Answer (score 0):

For above program your input is "(null)", So you are getting "(null)6". Here "6" is the output from `printf` (number of characters successfully printed).